# bounds of a Really simple triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $∫∫∫_{D}~~y ~dV$, where $D$ is the region below the plane $z=x+1$ , above the $xy$ plane and between the cylinders $x^2+y^2=1$, and $x^2+y^2=9$

one thing i dont get is the bounds of this integral in cylinderical coordinates.

why $ 1 \leq r \leq 3 $ and $ 0 \leq \theta \leq2\pi$

since $ 0 \leq z \leq r\cos{\theta}+1$ it shouldn't be the case.

for example when $\theta = \pi$ and $ r = 2$ ~~=>  $r\cos{\theta}+1 < 0$ !!

the bounds according to this site

https://www.varsitytutors.com/calculus_3-help/multiple-integration/triple-integrals

Answer (score 1):

The solution on Varsity Tutors is wrong.  (What did you expect with an online tutoring outfit?)  Since the problem says the region is above the $xy$-plane, the limits for $\theta$ can't be $0$ to $2\pi$.  This problem is do-able, but it's very messy.  Use symmetry to do twice the integral $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.  But this needs to be split into $0\leq \theta \arctan \leq \pi -\arctan 1/3$ and $\pi=\arctan 1/3 \leq  \theta \leq \pi.$

The limits for $r$ in the second integral are from $1$ to the line where $z=x+1$ intersects the plane.